# IndexOf can't find last element in a List

Tags: c#, indexof

Why does `IndexOf` fail to find last element in `List`, for this code?

```
  public List<Rule> rules = new List<Rule>();
  Rule n = new Rule();
  rules.Add(n);
  Console.WriteLine(n == rules.Last<Rule>()); //True
  dg_main.SelectedIndex = rules.IndexOf(n); //-1
```

**Answer:**
Thank you all for your time.
I was so confused with the situation that I didn't even saw that it wasn't IndexOf's fault.
It was the dg_main.SelectedIndex who changed the index. DataGrid was sorted.

Comment: IndexOf uses EqualityComparer (then finally Object.Equals() overridden or default implementation). == operator may be different. What's code for Rule class?

Comment: Can you highlight which pieces of code run together? I know you originally posted with a space between line 1 and the other lines, and since you can't have a public local variable, that may have been your attempt to indicate that line 1 is in one place and the remaining lines are elsewhere? A short but complete example we can copy and paste into (say) a console project would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a mistake in the part of code which you didn't show, because code below works correct:

```
[Test, Explicit]
public void Test()
{
  List<Rule> rules = new List<Rule>();
  Rule n = new Rule();
  rules.Add(n);
  Assert.AreEqual(n , rules.Last());
  Assert.AreEqual(0, rules.IndexOf(n));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IndexOf, as seen [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs#35ebfdcba4f0e942), uses the .Equals method of the EqualityComparer, which uses EqualityComparer.Default, resulting in [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs#d8e28972e89a3e86) comparer. As you can see, it uses the .Equals method, rather than the equality operator.

One big reason for this is that the equality operator, like all operators, is static, and thus does not properly call the operator you want unless the compiler has the right type at compile time.

The simplest workaround here it to implement .Equals and make it call the equality comparer.

```
// Equals overload for Rule objects
public bool override Equals(object obj)
{
    if(obj is Rule)
        return (Rule)obj == this; // Type cast here to ensure the right equality operator is called
    else return base.Equals(obj);
}
```